# Summarize Elevation in ArcGIS Pro not working?

Tags: arcgis-pro, elevation

The tool Summarize Elevation is not producing the typical fields ie Min, Mean, and Max elevation field values, although fields like Dem Res, Product Name, Source, Source URL are being produced.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: What tool parameter values are you using?

Comment: Help says _Oceans and other major water bodies are ignored in the calculations and do not effect the summary values._ Are your sampling geometries covering such areas?